# How to query low level of hiking road?

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to bring back to our 3D engine, some hiking path, or roads available for biking in a certain area.

Let say I try to do this for this small area:

```
[bbox:42.74449090412214,2.406005859375,43.280704585930835,3.3171844482421875]
;
(
  relation
    ["route"="hiking"]
    ["network"~"^.wn$"];
  way(r);
  >;
);
out;
```

This provides about 20Mb of data to deal with.

Is there a way to make the same query, but also to lowering details of the path?

Comment: What do you mean by "lowering details of the path"? Do you want to simplify the geometry (smooth the lines) or drop unwanted attribution from the data?

Comment: Yes that's, simplified geometry and not much details to reduce size / amount of datas to retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overpass API doesn't support simplifying geometry, it would return the query data as they can be found in the original OpenStreetMap data. You could however try to use `out geom` instead, which reduces the size of the output to 10 MB.

```
[bbox:42.74449090412214,2.406005859375,43.280704585930835,3.3171844482421875]
;
 relation
    ["route"="hiking"]
    ["network"~"^.wn$"];
  out geom;
```